# Jenkins Thread dead Exception

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

While executing a job in jenkins, sometimes this Exception occurs. The build will not stop, the next build will not start.

I start jenkins with `java -jar jenkins.war  --httpPort=8080` on Windows 64.

```
[31m四月 18, 2018 9:39:28 上午 hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
严重: A thread (AWT-EventQueue-0/2534) died unexpectedly due to an uncaught exception, this may leave your Jenkins in a bad way and is usually indicative of a bug in the code.
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment cannot be cast to sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the code that you are trying to run. There might be a possibility that you are using non UTF-8 characters that is leading to uncaught exceptions.